# Reading data from one table and using it to read data from another table

Tags: mysql

I'am trying to implement a small questionaire type of database in SQL Server 2008. The questions are multiple choice questions offerring four choices for each question. The questions reside in a Questions table. And the answer choices in another table called Answers. So, if there's a question in Questions with QuestionID=1, there'll be four tuples in Answers like:

```
QuestionId=1, AnswerID=a    
QuestionId=1, AnswerID=b    
QuestionId=1, AnswerID=c    
QuestionId=1, AnswerID=d.
```

I wish to write a single query that will return all the questions alongwith their respective answer-choices..One way is:

```
SELECT Q.Question, A.Answer   
FROM Q.Questions  
INNER JOIN A.Answers  
ON Q.QuestionID = A.QuestionID
```

But this returns the same question 4 times; once with each answer choice..Is there a way to return it only once, followed by its four answer choices, that too without using any iterators or cursors?

Thanks for your time :-)

Answer (score 0):

you should refine your query just reverse it

SELECT Q.Question, A.Answer
FROM Answers A 
INNER JOIN Questions Q
ON A.QuestionID = Q.QuestionID

May it will work